# Merging all rows with common value

Tags: python, csv, merge

Here's what I want to do using Python:

`file1.csv` contains:

```
Code,Expenditure
1,Meal
2,Taxi
3,Apartment
4,Laundry
```

`file2.csv` contains:

```
Code,Amount
1,150
2,90
2,100
2,85
3,5000
```

Now I want to merge them into another file (`output.csv`) that will look like this:

```
Code,Expenditure,Amount
1,Meal,150
2,Taxi,90
2,Taxi,100
2,Taxi,85
3,Apartment,5000
4,Laundry,
```

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try writing it yourself & come back if you have problems.  Or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: I suggest you look into the `csv module` of python. And a little birdie tells me a `dictionary data structure` would be useful here... ;)

Answer (score -1):

Read about file handling and python basics. As @Scott hunter told, you should try something, if you face any problems you can ask your question with your code here.

Anyway, **Here is what you need,**

```
a=open('a.txt','r').readlines()
b=open('b.txt','r').readlines()
for i in a:
    i=i.rstrip().split(',')
    for j in b:
         j=j.rstrip().split(',')
         if i[0]==j[0]:
             A=i[0],i[1],j[1]
             print ' '.join(A)
```